# JSON to .Net Epoch date conversion

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple WebAPI project.  I am passing JSON date in Epoch format
"pickupBefore":"/Date(1485360480-0800)/". When .Net catches it the DateTime shows year 1970. 
It is suppose to be January 25, 2017.
What should I do to get it in real time?

In my .Net application, I am catching the date as DateTime.  Behind  the scene the DateTime structure get filled with the date from 1970.  I was looking for something in that structure that will help me to convert it to real time DateTime.

I did looked at and tried [How do you convert epoch time in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c) before asking the question, but it did not help to solve my issue.
Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you convert epoch time in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883576/how-do-you-convert-epoch-time-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that your date string is in **Unix epoch time in *seconds*** but Microsoft's JSON date format is in **Unix epoch time in *milliseconds***, as explained in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx#intro_to_json_sidebarb).  Json.NET automatically recognizes date strings in Microsoft format and in doing so interprets the offset as being in ms not seconds, which explains why *the DateTime shows year 1970*, as 1970 is the beginning year of the Unix epoch.

You should fix your JSON so that the date format is completely consistent with Microsoft's format, which would be `"/Date(1485360480000-0800)/"`.  Better yet, you could switch to [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which is currently the preferred JSON format for dates and times anyway.

If for whatever reason you cannot correct your JSON format, you will need to disable Json.NET's automatic `DateTime` recognition and parsing, and create your own [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) inheriting from [`DateTimeConverterBase`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_DateTimeConverterBase.htm).

To disable Json.NET's automatic date recognition, set [`DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateParseHandling.htm) in [`JsonSerializerSettings`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm).  But if you cannot modify your overall serializer settings, you can disable date recognition on the containing type only by applying the converter from [Question 40632820](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632820/how-to-prevent-a-single-object-property-from-being-converted-to-a-datetime-when) to it, e.g.:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DateParseHandlingConverter), DateParseHandling.None)] // Disable Json.NET's built-in date time parsing function.
public class RootObject
{
    public DateTime pickupBefore { get; set; }
}
```

Next you will need to write your custom `JsonConverter`.  One option would be to duplicate all the logic of Newtonsoft's [`DateTimeUtils.TryParseDateTime()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/DateTimeUtils.cs#L380) and [`DateTimeUtils.TryParseDateTimeOffset()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/DateTimeUtils.cs#L453), in the process rewriting  [`DateTimeUtils.TryParseDateTimeMicrosoft()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/DateTimeUtils.cs#L522) and [`DateTimeUtils.TryParseDateTimeOffsetMicrosoft()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/DateTimeUtils.cs#L568) to parse epoch numbers in seconds not milliseconds.  I started to do this but realized there's a fair amount of code involved - more than is appropriate for a stackoverflow answer.  As an alternative, a quick-and-dirty hack would be to insert an extra `000` substring into the JSON to convert from seconds to milliseconds, like so:

```
public class MicrosoftSecondsDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            var s = ((string)token).Trim();
            if (s.StartsWith("/Date(", StringComparison.Ordinal) && s.EndsWith(")/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                // MS datetime format is in milliseconds as is shown here:
                // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx#intro_to_json_sidebarb
                // But our times are offsets in seconds.
                // Convert.
                var sb = new StringBuilder("\"\\/Date(");
                var insert = "000"; // Seconds to MS
                for (int i = 6; i < s.Length - 2; i++)
                {
                    if (s[i] == '-' || s[i] == '+') // Time zone marker
                    {
                        sb.Append(insert);
                        insert = string.Empty;
                    }
                    sb.Append(s[i]);
                }
                sb.Append(insert);
                sb.Append(")\\/\"");
                s = sb.ToString();
                var dt = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize(new StringReader(s), objectType);
                return dt;
            }
        }

        // Not a Microsoft date.
        return new JsonSerializer().Deserialize(token.CreateReader(), objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

It's not beautiful but does get the job done.  Then apply your converter to your type as follows:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DateParseHandlingConverter), DateParseHandling.None)] // Disable Json.NET's built-in date time parsing function.
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MicrosoftSecondsDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime pickupBefore { get; set; }
}
```

Or add it to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm) to change deserialization of `DateTime` strings for your entire data model.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fAc66f).