# Prevent Json.NET from interpreting a string as a date

Tags: date, json.net

I have some attributes returned from a rest service that are served as an array of name-value pairs.

In some cases the value is a date expressed in universal sortable format:
{
  "name": "Modification-Date",
  "value": "2017-11-13T15:15:13.968Z"
}

When it gets parsed by the deserialiser, the value is identified as a date but given that the object the pair is deserialised into has type string for both name and value, the date is then converted to string and it loses precision: "13/11/2017 15:15:13"

This is easily visible by using a converter for the NameValue type.

```
if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
{
    var item = JObject.Load(reader);

    return new NameValueFacet()
    {
        Name = item["name"].Value<string>(),
        Value = item["value"].Value<string>()
    };
}
```

item["value"].Type shows the type is Date.

How do I get to have Json.NET leave it as a string, "unparsed"?

Comment: Setting reader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None; before calling JObject.Load(reader) solves the problem. Is there any way I can just specify a Json Attribute on my NameValue class' Value property to get the same result without having to use a converter?

Comment: Please edit your question rather than putting that in a comment.

Comment: There is not an attribute for turning off date parsing on a single property, but you can turn it off globally by setting `DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None` in `JsonSerializerSettings` and passing the settings to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.  Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1y1bXM

Comment: Related?  [How to prevent a single object property from being converted to a DateTime when it is a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40632820/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Newtonsoft. See below.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<your_object>(your_json, new IsoDateTimeConverter{ DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyy" });
```