# Json.NET deserializing DateTimeOffset value fails for DateTimeOffset.MinValue without timezone

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc, deserialization, datetimeoffset

In my ASP.NET Core Web-API project, I'm getting a HTTP POST call to one of my API controllers.

While evaluating the JSON payload and deserializing its contents, Json.NET stumbles upon a DateTime value of `0001-01-01T00:00:00` and can't convert it to a DateTimeOffset property.

I notice that the value propably should represent the value of DateTimeOffset.MinValue, but its lack of a timezone seems to trip the deserializer up. I can only imagine that the DateTimeOffset.Parse tries to translate it to the hosts current timezone, which results in an underflow of DateTimeOffset.MinValue.

The property is pretty simplistic:

```
[JsonProperty("revisedDate", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public DateTimeOffset? RevisedDate { get; set; }
```

And here is the response sent to the client:

```
{
    "resource.revisedDate": [
        "Could not convert string to DateTimeOffset: 0001-01-01T00:00:00. Path 'resource.revisedDate', line 20, position 44."
    ]
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.2 and currently am in UTC + 2 (Germany).  The exception traceback and error message are here: https://pastebin.com/gX9R9wq0.

I can't fix the calling code, so I have to fix it on my side of the line.

But the question is: How?

Comment: Can't reproduce, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/krfPNn.  Also can't reproduce in UTC-05:00 using Json.NET version 10 or 11.2.  What time zone are you in?  What version of Json.NET are you using?

Comment: I'm using Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.2 and currently am in UTC + 2 (Germany).

Comment: Well if the problem is only reproducible in a time zone with a positive offset from UTC, that would be awkward.  Can you reproduce this in a console app and share the complete `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception, if any?

Comment: Here's the exception https://pastebin.com/gX9R9wq0

Comment: @dbc Here's the exception output from your demo https://pastebin.com/iAuXaJN6

Comment: Oh that's interesting -- it fails on the initial call to `DateTimeOffset.Parse(s);` without ever getting to Json.NET.  Can you share the traceback from this fiddle also?  https://dotnetfiddle.net/xtnFJf

Comment: Here you go https://pastebin.com/dRSjNGKP

Comment: OK, after setting my machine's time zone to "(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna" I was able to reproduce the problem.  Working on a workaround.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**The problem** seems reproducible only when the machine's time zone [`TimeZoneInfo.Local`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local.aspx) has a positive offset from UTC, e.g. *`(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna`*.  I was unable to reproduce it in time zones with a non-positive offset such as *`UTC-05:00`* or UTC itself.

Specifically, in [`JsonReader.ReadDateTimeOffsetString()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonReader.cs#L899) a call is made to `DateTimeOffset.TryParse` using `DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind`:

```
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParse(s, Culture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out dt))
{
    SetToken(JsonToken.Date, dt, false);
    return dt;
}
```

This apparently causes an underflow error in time zones with a positive UTC offset.  If in the debugger I parse using `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` instead, the problem is avoided.

You might want to [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) about this to Newtonsoft.  The fact that deserialization of a specific `DateTimeOffset` string fails only when the computer's time zone has certain values seems wrong.

**The workaround** is to use [`IsoDateTimeConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_IsoDateTimeConverter.htm) to deserialize your `DateTimeOffset` properties with [`IsoDateTimeConverter.DateTimeStyles`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_IsoDateTimeConverter_DateTimeStyles.htm) set to `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`.  In addition it is necessary to disable the automatic `DateTime` recognition built into `JsonReader` by setting [`JsonReader.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_DateParseHandling.htm), which must be done *before* the reader begins to parse the value for your `DateTimeOffset` properties.

First, define the following `JsonConverter`:

```
public class FixedIsoDateTimeOffsetConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTimeOffset) || objectType == typeof(DateTimeOffset?);
    }

    public FixedIsoDateTimeOffsetConverter() : base() 
    {
        this.DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal;
    }
}
```

Now, if you can modify the `JsonSerializerSettings` for your controller, use the following settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
    Converters = { new FixedIsoDateTimeOffsetConverter() },
};
```

If you cannot easily modify your controller's `JsonSerializerSettings` you will need to grab `DateParseHandlingConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40644970/3744182) to *[How to prevent a single object property from being converted to a DateTime when it is a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40632820/3744182)* and apply it as well as `FixedIsoDateTimeOffsetConverter` to your model as follows:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DateParseHandlingConverter), DateParseHandling.None)]
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("revisedDate", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(FixedIsoDateTimeOffsetConverter))]
    public DateTimeOffset? RevisedDate { get; set; }
}
```

`DateParseHandlingConverter` must be applied to the model itself rather than the `RevisedDate` property because the `JsonReader` will already have recognized `0001-01-01T00:00:00` as a `DateTime` before the call to `FixedIsoDateTimeOffsetConverter.ReadJson()` is made.

**Update**

In [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628374/json-net-deserializing-datetimeoffset-value-fails-for-datetimeoffset-minvalue-wi/50631270#comment88273316_50631270), [@RenéSchindhelm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1503584/ren%C3%A9-schindhelm) writes, *I created an issue to let Newtonsoft know*.  It is *[Deserialization of DateTimeOffset value fails depending on system's timezone #1731](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1731)*.

Comment: The workaround works. I [created an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1731) to let Newtonsoft know. Maybe they come up with a fix. I sincerely thank you dbc for providing this quality help here. +1

Comment: I'm guessing that having a 31-12-9999 23:59:59 date with a negative time zone will also throw an exception on parsing

Answer (score 8):

This is what I am using to fix the issue in .NET Core 3.

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore;
                options.SerializerSettings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal });
            });
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `DateTimeOffset` to `DateTime` solved the problem.

Comment: In scenarios where you are not concerned about the time zone offset, this is an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Json.NET version and then your input value and formatting. I'm trying the following example and it is working fine for me:

```
void Main()
{
    var json = @"{""offset"":""0001-01-01T00:00:00""}";
    var ds = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestDS>(json);
    Console.WriteLine(ds);
}
public class TestDS {
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("offset", NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public DateTimeOffset? DSOffset { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the output:

> DSOffset 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM -06:00

Comment: The problem is reproducible in time zones with a positive offset from UTC, e.g. *`(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna`*.  I was able to reproduce it after modifying my machine's time zone and re-running.